# JqueryUI Autocomplete , making drop up list rather than drop down in a footer menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-autocomplete, html-lists

I am using JqueryUI Autocomlete with the search box inside a menu. My problem is how to make the list returned by auocomplete to drop up instead of down in a footer based menu.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
 $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        delay:0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );

            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $( "#project-imgN" ).val( ui.item.imgN );
            $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.label );                
            $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", ui.item.icon );
            $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
            $( "#project-label" ).html( ui.item.label );
            $( "#project-link" ).attr("href", ui.item.url );
            $( "#project-keyword" ).val(ui.item.keyword );
            log( ui.item ?
                 ui.item.icon :
                 + this.value );
                    $('#log_holder').slideDown();
            $( ".text" ).fadeIn();    
            return false;
        },

        close: function(event, ui ) {
        function runEffect() {
        // get effect type from 
        var move = $( "#project-imgN" ).val();
        // run the effect
        $('#log').slideDown();
        cf.moveTo(move);

    };

     runEffect(); 
        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.value + "</a>" )

            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

The issue, I think is in:

```
  .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.value + "</a>" )

            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

or is it  in altering the CSS of the ul ?
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From what I understand, this question seems to have an answer that should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501759/how-to-place-autocomplete-menu-above-the-text-input

Comment: this question has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644624/13958264